# Format exception on logging configuration in application.properties

Tags: quarkus

We are trying to use property extensions based on [chapter 5](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference) in the Quarkus guide. I'm looking in particular at the line:

`${expression:value} - Provides a default value after the : if the expansion doesn’t find a value.`

When we define a property like this:

```
quarkus.log.console.format=${QUARKUS-LOG-FORMAT:%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c{3.}] (%t) %s%e%n}
```

I get an error message:

`LogManager error of type FORMAT_FAILURE: Formatting error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'p'`

Apparently the `{`and `}` are interpreted as part of the expression.

Note also: this is the default logging format string from the Quarkus documentation.

I can circumvent that by defining an additional property and substituting that into the `quarkus.log.console.format` like this:

```
bro.log.format=%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c{3.}] (%t) %s%e%n
quarkus.log.console.format=${QUARKUS-LOG-FORMAT:${bro.log.format}}
```

But is there an elegant way to do this in a one liner? (in other words: how can I escape `{`and `}`)

IMHO: It would be good to add this to the Quarkus documentation. Logging is typically something you might want to define external (configmap or other means).

Comment: Have you tried '\' as an escape char?

Comment: This `quarkus.log.console.format=${QUARKUS-LOG-FORMAT:%d\{HH:mm:ss\} %-5p [%c\{3.\}] (%t) %s%e%n}` gives the same exception

Comment: backscaping the square brackets also like this: `quarkus.log.console.format=${QUARKUS-LOG-FORMAT:%d\{HH:mm:ss\} %-5p \[%c\{3.\}\] (%t) %s%e%n}` also gives the same exception

Comment: I tried wrapping the value in ' and " as well. Same problem